# What is the point of uniqueness theorem?

Tags: calculus, information-theory, entropy

I am trying to understand the Shannon-Khinchin uniqueness theorem which states that entropy is the unique function that can measure uncertainty. This is what I have understood and may not be correct; so, if you think that it is wrong please tell me about it because thus you can help a lot:)

However, I also understood that the entropy itself was derived primarily for measuring uncertainty as it is a mean value of a set of uncertainties. So, if it was created to measure the uncertainty then why do we prove that it is the unique function to measure it? I mean if there would be plenty of function to choose from to measure it then existence of such a theorem is comprehensible but otherwise it is hard to understand its existence. I guess I am missing something in my understanding of why do we need such a theorem and I would really want to hear from you about what is the point of its existence.

Comment: This has always puzzled me, too.  I get the impression that this theorem was an afterthought, a mathematical way of saying something nice about an already-decided definition.

Comment: @kimchi-lover nice to hear that I am not alone in such thinking:) I also have thought about that this theorem only proves that there is no other function that could measure information and that the function derived and later called entropy is the only possible function there is? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: I also think the whole information theory could go smoothly without that uniqueness theorem. But when I read the proof of it, I found it quite interesting and beautiful. It's up to everyone self to judge whether that counts as a "point" of the theorem.

Comment: When I first saw the definition of "entropy" in the information-theoretic way, it was not clear at all why its definition is natural and how one would come up with it (and I am still to see a satisfying deduction for that definition avoiding Shannon-Khinchin axioms altogether).The Shannon-Khinchin axioms are what one would naturally expect for any good definition of "information" to satisfy.The uniquess theorem says that there is only one way to define it (which just so happens to be as the integral of $x\log x$). So in some way it gives us a computational way to work with entropy/information.

Comment: So what I mean is that I don't really care what the formula/definition is, but whether it makes sense and can be interpreted in a meaningful way. The Shannon-Khinchin axioms are (for me) a much better motivator for entropy, and the uniqueness theorem says that all of that makes sense and that the theory is quite rigid.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Quite good point, don't you consider making it an answer?